# Windows phone 7: Get the name of photo stored in Libary picture?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I need to get the name of a photo which is stored in Library Picture. I have a button to create new `EventHandler<PhotoResult>` and an image control to display the photo. The photo must be chosen in Library Picture of WP like this:

[image]

I used photo chooser:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     PhotoChooserTask objPhotoChooser = new PhotoChooserTask();
     objPhotoChooser.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(PhotoChooseCall);
     objPhotoChooser.Show();
}

void PhotoChooseCall(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    switch (e.TaskResult)
    {
        case TaskResult.OK:
            BinaryReader objReader = new BinaryReader(e.ChosenPhoto);
            image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(e.OriginalFileName));
            MessageBox.Show("Photo's name: " + e.OriginalFileName.ToString());
            break;
        case TaskResult.Cancel:
            MessageBox.Show("Cancelled");
            break;
        case TaskResult.None:
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing Entered");
            break;
    }
}
```

But the output is path of the photo, NOT the name:

> Photo's name: \Applications\Data\C80566AB-E17E-495C-81A1-3FCAE34D3DEDE\Data\PlatformData\PhotoChooser-a8208960-3597-40fc-9b4f-869afcf822b6.jpg

How can I get the name of the photo??? 
(I need to get **PhotoChooser-a8208960-3597-40fc-9b4f-869afcf822b6.jpg**)

Answer (score 2):

The usual way is to use `System.IO.Path.GetFileName()`.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string with "\" as delimiter and the last entry of the resulting array contains the name of the photo. Should be easy to perform with C#.